# Super User bio background

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, style

On SO, and MSO, on a user's profile, the section on the right used for the bio has a grey background.

On SU, it does not. The text is just on the same white background as the rest of the page.

Yet it still has the same padding as SO/MSO, causing it to look out of place because it is (seemingly without reason) aligned almost, but not quite, with the `edit | new login` on your own profile.

Could a background be put on this, or the text shifted up so it lines up completely?

Comment: I believe this should be `[status-completed]`, since it seems to have been changed.

Answer (score 2):

Feels the same over in Server Fault where they have no background, but a chunky dotted border to the left of the bio section.

That is, the alignment looks the same across the SOFU platter with or without the `background-color` or the `border` set.